# A strategy for testing the Dropbox iOS API

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing, dropbox

(Apologies to moderators as this isn't a very specific question.)

I'm wondering if people can suggest a good strategy for implementing dropbox API tests. I have an app that suffers from some file duplication issues when uploading, and some of these seem to occur only in poor network conditions. I'd like to have a comprehensive test suite that can give me the best assurance possible that my implementation is bug free.

Thanks.